# extract string and integers from text file and put them into array C language

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a problem here and I can't figure it out so any help would be appreciated , I have a text file that has strings and integers separated by comma and I want to extract the integers and put them into an array and extract the strings and put them into another array and this is the text file sample :

> 1,2,dfds,dv,h,dfdd,wfdsf,e,3,4,yee,rss,a,6,8,5

and this is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "vector.h"

void readDataByDelimiter(const char* File, vector *v)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen(File, "r");

    //read file into array
    int numberArray[16];
    int i;
    char b[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%d,%c,",&numberArray[i] , &b[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
        printf("Number is: %c\n\n", b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your results?

Comment: Random numbers such as Number is : -4847392 and random symbols

Comment: printf("Number is: %d\n\n", *numberArray[i]); this works?

Comment: Yeah its compiling but its not the output the i want

Comment: First, the data is kind of random, but your `fscanf` assumes a number/char pattern. Second, the data contains strings, but you are using the char (`%c`) format specifier.

Comment: No i changed the code haha, try to change your line with this printf("Number is: %d\n\n", *numberArray[i]);

Comment: Your read loop assumes your input alternates between integers and *single characters*, but your example doesn't follow that pattern.  Secondly, `%c` is used to read *single characters*, not strings.  Similarly, `b` is sized to hold 100 *characters*, not 100 *strings*.

Comment: Thanks johnny , but what u suggest me to do cuz i'm totally new to c language and i've spent hours on this thing with no hope :p

Answer (score 1):

To read only integers and skip anything else you can use following approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * f = fopen("file.txt","r");
    int number;
    int res;
    while((res = fscanf(f, "%d,",&number)) != EOF){
        if(res == 1){
            printf("%d,", number);
        }
        else{
            fscanf(f,"%*[^,],");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here when res is 1 - you can add the number read into array.
When res is 0 - you need to skip everything till next ,
And when fscanf returns EOF - it means end of file is riched

EDIT2

I do not really see what is stopping you from extending my sample to do what you want. Here is the slightly extended version

```
#include <stdio.h>

int skip(FILE* f) {
    for(;;)
    {
        int res = fgetc(f);
        if(res == EOF)
            return 0;

        if(res == ',')
            return 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    FILE * f = fopen("file.txt","r");
    int number;
    int res;
    while((res = fscanf(f, "%d,",&number)) != EOF) {
        if(res == 1) {
            printf("number - %d\n", number);
            //add number to array
        }
        else {
            char buffer[100];
            if(fscanf(f,"%99[^,]",buffer ) == 1)
            {
                printf("string - %s\n", buffer);
                //add buffer to string array
            }
            if(!skip(f))
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although not in OP's sample, with "123,,456", code has an infinite loop.  2nd `,` never read.  Suggest `fscanf(f,"%*[^,]"); fscanf(f,",");` or just `fgetc(f)`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I do not really see what is stopping you. But I have updated the second example to include the string reading as well. You just need to add numbers and string to your arrays

Comment: Thank you -Artemy i'm gonna try it as soon i reach home

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to read in line by line, split each line into tokens, check each token if it is a number and add it to the `numArray` or, otherwise, to a `stringArray`.
See the following code which uses `strtok` for tokenizing and `sscanf` to read/check for a number. Hope it helps.

```
void readDataByDelimiter(const char* File, char* stringArray[], int intArray[], int maxcount)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen(File, "r");

    int intCount = 0;
    int stringCount = 0;

    char line[1000];
    while (myFile && fgets(line,sizeof(line),myFile)) {
        char* token = strtok(line, ",");
        while (token) {
            int num;
            if (sscanf(token, "%d", &num) == 1) {  // successfully scanned an int?
                if (intCount < maxcount) {
                    intArray[intCount++] = num;
                }
            }
            else {  // otherwise use as string
                if (stringCount < maxcount) {
                    stringArray[stringCount++] = strdup(token);
                }
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int intArray[16] = { 0 };
    char* stringArray[16] = { NULL };

    readDataByDelimiter(DATAFILE, stringArray, intArray, 16);

    printf("numbers: \n");
    for (int i=0; intArray[i]; i++) {
        printf("%d ", intArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\nstrings: \n");
    for (int i=0; stringArray[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s ", stringArray[i]);
        free(stringArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
numbers: 
1 2 3 4 6 8 5 
strings: 
dfds dv h dfdd wfdsf e yee rss a
```

Comment: Thank you soo much stephan , much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample input doesn't follow a clear pattern of integer-string-integer-string, etc., you'll probably want to read each item as a text string first, then convert any integer strings to their corresponding `int` values using `strtol` or a similar function.

So how do you do that?

First, you need to set aside a buffer to read input text.

```
char buf[SIZE+1];
```

where `SIZE` is the length of the largest expected string.  Remember that in C, a string is a *sequence* of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in *arrays* of `char` (or `wchar_t` for wide strings), not single `char` objects.

Secondly, we need to read all input *as text*, but we don't want to include the `,` delimiter or the newline in that text.  So instead of using `%s`, we'll use the `%[` conversion specifier, which allows us to specify which characters we *don't* want to be part of the input.  We also want to make sure we don't read more characters than `buf` is sized to hold, so we'll use an explicit width in the conversion specifier as well.  *Unfortunately*, `scanf` requires the width to be hard-coded as part of the specifier (you can't use `*` and add the width as an extra argument like you can with `printf`).  It's a major pain in the butt, so to get around it we'll have to get creative with a macro:

```
#define SIZE 20
#define FMT2(x) #x
#define FMT(x) "%" FMT2(x) "[^,\n]"
```

We'll use the macro like so:

```
scanf( FMT(SIZE), buf );
```

After macro expansion, that will become

```
scanf( "%20[^,\n]", buf );  // note no & operator on buf - not used for array expressions
```

which means, "read text from standard input until we see a comma or newline *OR* we've read 20 characters, and store the result to `buf`".

Finally, we need to check each input to see if it was an integer string (`"1"`, `"234"`, etc.) or not.  The easy way to do that is to use the `strtol` library function, which will attempt to convert the string to an integer equivalent.  It will return a pointer to the first character that was not part of a legal integer string - if that character is anything other than whitespace or a string terminator, then the input was not a valid integer:

```
char *chk;
int tmp = strtol( buf, &chk, 0 );
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  // tmp is not a valid integer string
}
```

The following is a standalone program that puts all of that together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define FMT2(x) #x
#define FMT(x) "%" FMT2(x)  "[^,\n]"

int main( void )
{
  int iValues[100];
  char sValues[100][SIZE+1];

  size_t iCount = 0;
  size_t sCount = 0;
  int    r = 1;

  char buf[SIZE+1] = {0};

  /**
   * Loop until one of the following is true:
   *
   *   - End of file or error on input
   *   - We see the string "end" (which will be included in the list of strings)
   *   - We've read 100 strings or integers
   */
  while ( strcmp( buf, "end" ) && r == 1 && iCount < 100 && sCount < 100 )
  {
    /**
     * The "%*c" tells scanf to read and discard the next character
     * from the input stream; if we don't do that, the trailing comma
     * or newline will foul up the next read and we'll get stuck in
     * an infinite loop.  
     */ 
    if ( ( r = scanf( FMT(SIZE) "%*c", buf )) == 1)
    {
      char *chk = 0;
      int tmp = (int) strtol( buf, &chk, 0 );
      if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
      {
        /**
         * The input string contains at least one non-numeric character,
         * so we add it to the sValues array.
         */
        strcpy( sValues[sCount++], buf );
      }
      else
      {
        /**
         * The input string is an integer, so we add it to the iValues
         * array
         */
        iValues[iCount++] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < iCount; i++ )
    printf( "iValues[%zu] = %d\n", i, iValues[i] );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < sCount; i++ )
    printf( "stringValues[%zu] = %s\n", i, sValues[i] );

  return 0;
}
```

Run on your sample input, the output is:

```
$ ./delim
1,2,dfds,dv,h,dfdd,wfdsf,e,3,4,yee,rss,a,6,8,5
iValues[0] = 1
iValues[1] = 2
iValues[2] = 3
iValues[3] = 4
iValues[4] = 6
iValues[5] = 8
iValues[6] = 5
stringValues[0] = dfds
stringValues[1] = dv
stringValues[2] = h
stringValues[3] = dfdd
stringValues[4] = wfdsf
stringValues[5] = e
stringValues[6] = yee
stringValues[7] = rss
stringValues[8] = a
```

One issue that this code doesn't deal with - if you enter a string longer than the buffer is sized to hold, it will be split into two (or more) strings (with one character thrown away because of the `%*c` specifier):

```
$ ./delim
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
stringValues[0] = abcdefghijklmnopqrst
stringValues[1] = vwxyz
```

You'll want to decide how to deal with that, but for now this should get you going.